# Calling SQL procedure multiple times takes excessive time

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, stored-procedures

**C# Code:**

```
private void picInward_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     for(DataRow dr in dtData.Rows)
     {
         UpdateLocation(dr["DocId"].ToString(), Convert.ToInt32(dr["SiteId"].ToString()));
     }
}


private void UpdateLocation(string DocId, int LocId)
{
     try
     {
         ArrayList sqlParameterArrayList = new ArrayList();

         string strQry = "UpdateDocLoc";

         SqlParameter sqpDocId = new SqlParameter("DocId", SqlDbType.VarChar);
         sqpDocId.Value = DocId;
         sqlParameterArrayList.Add(sqpDocId);

         SqlParameter sqpLocId = new SqlParameter("LocId", SqlDbType.Int);
         sqpLocId.Value = LocId;
         sqlParameterArrayList.Add(sqpLocId);

         DBHelper.ExecuteStoredProcedure(strQry, sqlParameterArrayList);
    }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {
         MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "Alert", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
    }
}
```

**SQL PROCEDURE:**

```
CREATE procedure UpdateDocLoc
@DocId as varchar(50),
@LocId as int
AS
BEGIN
    update DocMaster set SiteId = @LocId where DocumentID = @DocId

    Insert into HSDocMaster(DocId, LocId, ModifiedDate, IsDeleted)
    value(@DocId, @LocId, GETDATE(), 0)
END
```

This is just a sample code, I relatively have a very huge procedure code which has to update multiple tables and also some insert values in other tables plus the table has a trigger which fires on update. I have to update nearly 1000 odd records and this method of repeatedly calling the procedure is too time consuming. Is there a better way to get this done reasonably faster?

Comment: Instead for calling Store Procedure each time for different DocId, LocId individually. Create a Datatable having all DocId and LocId. Pass the Datatable to Store Procedure. In store procedure perform the desire operation. Below link has nice information on how to do this http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/87b416/passing-datatable-to-storeprocedure-as-parameter-in-C-Sharp/

Comment: Table Valued Parameter? I was looking into it but didn't quite find the kind of article that would help me. Let me just check this one.

Comment: @Abhijit_Srikumar Ok I got how to pass a datatable but what sorta changes do I have to make in my SQL Procedure to use this datatable?

Comment: For Store Procedure , You have to consider User Defined Table Type as input parameter. It behaves like a Table variable. So Join, Data Manipulation is similar that of table. http://aspalliance.com/1891_Pass_Tables_to_Stored_Procedure__Table_Valued_Parameter.2